# PHP and ordering persons randomly but always in same order when using same data

Tags: php, math

I'm using PHP. My target is to order persons who have same total points. When points are 75, the order needs to be same every time when the script is executed. When points are 80 or something else, the order has to change, but it needs to be same every time when the script is executed and total points are 80.

```
User ID 258 = Milla
User ID 289 = E-P
User ID 290 = Jari
User ID 449 = Pepe
User ID 633 = Elias
User ID 634 = Virpi
User ID 635 = Jaakko
User ID 636 = Joona
```

Let's say that the total points are 75.

```
$total = 75;

# $user_id[0] means first number of $user_id
# for example: if $user_id is 634, then $user_id[0] = 6

$count = $user_id[0] . ($user_id % 2) . ($user_id * 0.33);

$number = bcdiv("$total", "$count", 16);
list($temp, $number) = explode(".", "$number");
$number = ($number % $user_id) . $number;
```

When I use this code for every person and order them by `$number` which is a string, the descending order will be this:

```
E-P
Joona
Elias
Jari
Jaakko
Pepe
Milla
Virpi
```

I want the script be as fair as possible. I mean that if a person has, for example, high user ID, he should not be treated better with all total points than a person whose user ID is lower.

What do you think? Should I improve the code? Or are everybody on the same line and treated equally when the total points will be changed?

Oh yeah, one more thing. The script needs to run as quickly as possible. If you have ideas, please feel free to tell me.

**Update**

I ended up using this kind of code:

```
$total = 75;
$user_id = 258;
$count = $user_id * 0.33;

$number = bcdiv("$total", "$count", 16);
list($temp, $number) = explode(".", "$number");
$number[0] = $number[10]; # get 10th number to 1st number
```

If there are ways to optimize it, I would like to hear. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is really unclear. I'm a bit confused by what your trying to do with the second line in your code snippet. You're referencing the value at `$user_id[0]` which means presumably that `$user_id` is an array. But then you're taking the modulus of the array and multiplying the array by `0.33`? Am I missing something?...

Comment: @War10ck I have added a comment to my question. `$user_id[0]` is same as the first letter (or number in this case) of string `$user_id`.

Answer (score 3):

If you seed the random number generator, then the randomness will be the same based on the seed. This will always generate the same shuffled array:

```
$total = 75;
srand($total);
shuffle($user_id);
```

Then if you set `$total = 80` you will get a different shuffled array, but it will always be the same when `$total = 80`.

Comment: Good to know. In this case I do not want to shuffle all keys of the array. Only those who have same total points needs to be sorted by me.

Comment: OK, so in you're example how did you get only those with the same points?

Comment: This is just an example. In real life I have a huge multidimensional array which is sorted a couple of times.

Comment: Well, this is how you do it regardless.  If there's more to it then you need to show it.

Comment: I updated my solution to the opening message. It seems to work pretty well, I think.